# How do you ask questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How do you ask questions (or for help) on Stack Overflow? I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508469/how-to-i-decompile-and-recompile-apk-files?noredirect=1) which seems to have been put on hold because I wasn't specific enough.

I am very new to Android decompiling/recompiling and development, and I do not know how to be any more specific with my lack of knowledge in that area.

It's weird, but it seems like every post I find on Google that I think might be useful to me, even in other areas of programming that I'm more familiar with, end up with little to no helpful answers.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how I can have better results here on Stack Overflow? I even tried offering an incentive of US$10 to my post, but I had no luck.

Comment: Read the tour, once.

Comment: this question itself is pretty much a good description of what not to do. Your question should be specific to programming, should include sample code of what you have tried, and ideally not include monetary compensation. You may find more help on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: trying to offer $$$ for answers...just dont

Comment: Well I'll try not to offer compensation anymore. But I just didn't know what else to get some help on a subject. I included commands I was running in CMD. But there's not really anything programming related to add into the script. So is it just that subject of decompiling/recompiling is not suitable for stackoverflow? I'll definitely check out that android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You might also want to consider following [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72987/stack-overflow-academy) on Area 51.

Answer (score 10):

Read [What Topics Can I Ask About Here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

and then read [How do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

There are similar articles on all Stack Exchange sites, including Android.